# What is the best way to convert a TreeSet to populate a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, treeset

What is the best way to convert a TreeSet to populate a HashMap using Java ? 
For example:

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>> sortedset =
  new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>();
```

to

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

Comment: what does TreeSet have `key` or `value`, what about other one ?

Comment: You're going from only values to a key-value data structure.  What would be the actual keys involved in the map?

Answer (score 4):

I could be wrong, but i don't think Java has anything built in to do this. Your best bet is to do it manually (which is pretty straightforward):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : sortedSet)
    map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```